22.04LTS and zfs-dkms
Having run into the update problems with ZFS, I now can't stop it trying to build zfs-dkms every time I use apt. Which is deeply annoying:
Setting up zfs-dkms (2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.4) ...
Removing old zfs-2.1.5 DKMS files...
Deleting module zfs-2.1.5 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new zfs-2.1.5 DKMS files...
Building for 6.5.0-28-generic
Building initial module for 6.5.0-28-generic
configure: error: 
    *** None of the expected "bops->release()" interfaces were detected.
    *** This may be because your kernel version is newer than what is
    *** supported, or you are using a patched custom kernel with
    *** incompatible modifications.
    ***
    *** ZFS Version: zfs-2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.4
    *** Compatible Kernels: 3.10 - 5.19
    
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/zfs-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/zfs/2.1.5/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package zfs-dkms (--configure):
 installed zfs-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 zfs-dkms

So how can I either:

fix the problem
tell apt to ignore zfs-dkms updates

the (non-boot)zfs pool is working just fine. Is the solution to remove zfs-dkms? If so, what happens to the running pool? I'm VERY keen not to lose the pool and have to restore from backup, as it's 12TB and I really don't have time to rebuild that.
